# How to generate specific IDs for USB ports in Java?

Tags: java, usb

I am developing an application using Java. I am connecting 10 USB devices through external USB ports. I want a specific ID when I connect a device with a specific port. So, for example, if I connect a device on 10th port, I should get a specific ID for that port; which will help me in showing that device in 10th position only. I tried Jusb and other similar third party APIs but they didn't work out. Please suggest some techniques to accomplish this.

Comment: @Panther Please don't use backticks for non-code, see e.g. [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7437/88) why

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried The JSR-80 API (javax.usb) as explain here http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-usb/index.html

Comment: Yes I tried that, but I am not getting jar for import usb.core.*; I am using windows 7 (64 bit) Os and I think these APIs are not updated.